# Is there a way to stop and refresh css animation inside two nested carousels by pressing the next button?

Tags: jquery, css

I have two carousels, one is nested in another. Both work "correctly" like left 8second and right 2 seconds. left is fading in and right is in a loop, all the time showing 2 images. if I press next button from the left side carousel to come to next slide where also is a new slide for left side and two new for the right side.

I came across that the css from the previous animation is still playing so if someone manually presses next, the. next slid will just start when the first one stops.

So I want to reload the css or another workaround to force the next slide to start immediately. anyone a clue for me?

HTML Markup:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="left-side">
<img"/></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col right-side">
                        <div class="slideshow-container">
                            <div class="slideshow-inner"">
                                <div class="mySlides animate-right"><img src="slide-check-right-side-1.png" /></div>
                                <div class="mySlides animate-right"><img src="slide-check-right-side-2.png" " /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <div class="left-side"><img src="slide-check-left-side-2.png"/></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col right-side">
                        <div class="slideshow-container">
                            <div class="slideshow-inner">
                                <div class="mySlides animate-right"><img src="slide-check-right-side-2-1.png" /></div>
                                <div class="mySlides animate-right"><img src="slide-check-right-side-2-2.png" /></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
<a id="button-prev" class="carousel-control-prev button-prev" href="#carousel" role="button">Prev</a>
<a id="button-next" class="carousel-control-next button-next" href="#carousel" role="button">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myTimer,
    slideshowContainer,
    element,
    slideIndex = 1;
function plusSlides(e) {
    clearInterval(myTimer),
    showSlides(e < 0 ? slideIndex -= 1 : slideIndex += 1),
    myTimer = -1 === e ? setInterval((function() {
        plusSlides(e + 2)
    }), 4e3) : setInterval((function() {
        plusSlides(e + 1)
    }), 4e3)
}
function currentSlide(e) {
    clearInterval(myTimer),
    myTimer = setInterval((function() {
        plusSlides(e + 1)
    }), 4e3),
    showSlides(slideIndex = e)
}
function showSlides(e) {
    var t,
        n = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"),
        l = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (e > n.length && (slideIndex = 1), e < 1 && (slideIndex = n.length), t = 0; t < n.length; t++)
        n[t].style.display = "none";
    for (t = 0; t < l.length; t++)
        l[t].className = l[t].className.replace(" activeShow", "");
    n[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block",
    l[slideIndex - 1].className += " activeShow"
}
window.addEventListener("load", (function() {
    showSlides(slideIndex),
    myTimer = setInterval((function() {
        plusSlides(1)
    }), 4e3),
    slideshowContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow-inner")[0]
})),
pause = () => {
    clearInterval(myTimer)
},
resume = () => {
    clearInterval(myTimer),
    myTimer = setInterval((function() {
        plusSlides(slideIndex)
    }), 4e3)
}
```

CSS:

```
.animate-right {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  animation: animate-right .5s;
}

@keyframes animate-right {
  from {
    right: -50vh;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.mySlides {
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: cyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: -50vw;
}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 50vw;
  width: 50vw;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

}
```

I tried to stop and refresh but some it's not working:

```
    document.querySelector('.button-next').onclick = function(){
  requestAnimation( this );
};

var requestAnimation = function( obj ){
  obj.style.animation = 'none';
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    obj.style.animation = 'animate-right 0.5s';
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".activate").click(function() {
        $('.mySlides').addClass('active');
        $('.mySlides').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API

Comment: how can I mix my js with that api? or do I have to write completely new code also for the css-js mixed animation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This might help you: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-play-and-stop-css-animation-using-jquery.php Personally, I would suggest using `.animate()` instead of CSS for a higher degree of control.

Comment: I have also found a large number of Syntax issues in your HTML. For example, you have: `<img"/>` and `<div class="slideshow-inner"">`which are not good HTML. Those need to be cleaned up first.